# Open a ModalPopupExtender on an UpdatePanel using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, webforms

I'm trying to open a ModalPopup with JavaScript, and i've searched here on stackoverflow and the general advice seems be to use something like this:

```
$('#inputAdd').live("click", function () {
    $('#addRow').show();
    $find('<%=mpeIndications.BehaviorID %>').show();
});
```

Where #inputAdd is an html input image that i have in the ModalPopup, its objective is to show a row (#addRow) where a TextBox is shown. However, when i click on the #inputAdd button, it show the row, but then the ModalPopup hide, I think the reason maybe because there is an UpdatePanel that include the ModalPopup, I am right? In that case which may be a solution? I've putted some of the code I've in the .ascx. Thanks.

```
<table class="content-box">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
             <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upAppointments">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnIndicationsHidden" Style="display: none;" />
                                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlIndications" CssClass="modalPanel" Style="display: none;">
                                    <table class="content-box">
                                        <tr>
                                           <td>
                                               <table style="width: 100%;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                           <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlShowCurrentIndication" Style="padding: 13px 8px 8px 8px">
                                                                <table style="width: 100%; border: 0;">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td style="width: 30%; vertical-align: top;" rowspan="2">
                                                                        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="gvProfiles" OnDataBound="gvProfiles_DataBound"
                                                                            DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" Style="white-space: nowrap;" />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;" class="contentBox">
                                                                        <table style="width: 100%;">
                                                                            <tbody id="showTable">
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td id="indicacionestd" runat="server">
                                                                                        Indicaciones:
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <asp:BulletedList ID="blIndicaciones" DataTextField="Valor" runat="server">
                                                                                        </asp:BulletedList>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td id="contraindicacionestd" runat="server">
                                                                                        Contraindicaciones:
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <asp:BulletedList ID="blContraindicaciones" DataTextField="Valor" runat="server">
                                                                                        </asp:BulletedList>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                            <tbody style="display: none;" id="addRow">
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td style="text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;" class="colSepGran">
                                                                                        Nombre:
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr class="filSepGranRA">
                                                                                    <td class="colSepGran">
                                                                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbName" CssClass="txtNoWidth" Width="150px" ToolTip="Especifique el nombre del perfil"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                        <act:FilteredTextBoxExtender runat="server" ID="ftbeName" FilterMode="ValidChars"
                                                                                            FilterType="UppercaseLetters, LowercaseLetters, Custom" TargetControlID="txbName"
                                                                                            ValidChars="ñ Ñ ' á é í ó ú Á É Í Ó Ú ü Ü ." />
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                                                                        <table style="width: 100%;">
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    &nbsp;
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <input type="image" src="../../App_Themes/Theme/Images/AppIcons/add.png/" id="inputAdd"
                                                                                        title="Adicionar perfil">
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <input type="image" src="../../App_Themes/Theme/Images/AppIcons/add_document.png"
                                                                                        id="inputAddSimple" title="Adicionar indicación" />
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <input type="image" src="../../App_Themes/Theme/Images/AppIcons/edit.png" id="inputEdit"
                                                                                        title="Editar perfil" />
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imbRemoveProfile" ToolTip="Eliminar perfil" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme/Images/AppIcons/delete.png" />
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    &nbsp;
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td colspan="2">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </asp:Panel>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <act:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeIndications" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlIndications"
                                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" TargetControlID="btnIndicationsHidden" CancelControlID="imbCloseIndications"
                                BehaviorID="mpeIndications">
                            </act:ModalPopupExtender>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        </table>
                  </ContentTemplate>
             </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then try this approach:

Add a hidden link for ModalPopup Extender to attach to(which will NEVER be used)

```
<a href="#" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" 
   onclick="return false" ID="dummyLink" runat="server">dummy</a>
```

Add the ID of the hidden link to the `ModalPopupExtender`

```
<act:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeIndications" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlIndications"
     BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
     TargetControlID="dummyLink" 
     CancelControlID="imbCloseIndications"
     BehaviorID="mpeIndications">
```

Showing the modal popup

```
$find('MyMPE').show();
```

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View38736C2B-BAD3-418A-A5B0-DAC4F1A5A83A.htm

Comment: No, it also hides, I changed the ASP.NET Button Control named btnIndicationsHidden for the <a> element you posted to see if that was the case but it doesn't. The button i mention seems to me it does the same function as the <a> element identified as dummyLink that you posted. Thanks for answering anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Model Dialog Asp.Net With Jquery](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2012/02/model-dialog-aspnet.html)

Comment: Isn't exactly the ModalPopupExtender what they're using but i've been evaluating using jQueryUI for the modals since a while, maybe should be time to give it a try.

Comment: Just let me see if I somebody can make a little more clear what's happening here, but is good to have a backup plan, thanks.